# Restrict WCF client from accessing certain public classes and methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have the following in my project.

> WarehouseAPI.Core.dll // contains all data access code.
>
> WCF service // references the WarehouseAPI.Core.dll  library.

when the wcf client consumes the service it gets access to all the public methods and classes in WarehouseAPI.Core.dll but I just want to grant access only to certain classes and methods only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - the WCF service will only access the methods and classes in WarehouseAPI.Core.dll that it needs to, and anyone using the service will only be able to access the methods the service exposes,

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very generic, but... Create WarehouseAPI_WCF.Core.dll which includes only the public methods that you want to be shown, and they call WarehouseAPI.Core.dll. Point your WCF service to WarehouseAPI_WCF.Core.dll

Depending how your class is structured you can use inheritance and create private methods to hide the public methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the contract for a WCF service (the `IService1` style interface), then any client connecting to that service will see **all** methods defined in that service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomething();

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomethingElse();

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomethingTotallyDifferent();
}
```

That's by design, and it's a **good thing**.

So if your `IService1` interface exposes *too much*, then you need to break it up into a smaller "core" and the larger "extended" version (---> adhering to the *Interface Segregating Principle* of object-oriented design).

Then you can expose these two services separately, and allow certain clients to only connect to the "core" service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1Core
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomething();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1Extended : IService1Core
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomethingElse();

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomethingTotallyDifferent();
}
```

Since `IService1Extended` descends from `IService1Core`, in the end, that "extended" service will still offer **all** the functionality of the original service. But now you can have an endpoint that *only* exposes the `IService1Core` contract and thus limit clients connecting to that endpoint to call just `DoSomething()` - and no other methods (since on that service contract, no other methods are defined)